# Show New Items Since Last Login On Dashboard When User Logs In Again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Searched through and didn't find any good resources/tutorials, **if someone could please explain how to generally get this done/how it would work or  even point me to a direction**

I am wanting to display a notice that says 'new Comments' were made since the last time a user was logged in. This notice will appear on the dashboard the next time they login in.

I read somewhere that I may need to make a 'last_action' column in the User table, but they didn't clarify much after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you add another column to your `users` table, called exactly that, `last_action_at`. When user performs any activity (navigates to pages, clicks buttons, etc), you write the time of the action to that field.

Then later, when he logs in, you fetch that value (which would be time of the last action in his last visit) and select all comments that have `created_at` greater than this value. Now you have all data necessary to render that `notice`.

Comment: The problem with this though is once the user performs a new action the last_action_at is overwritten and you can't go back to whatever notices the user should have (unless he's smart enough to browser back - relying on the cache).

To fix this you take the last_action_at date and put it in the users session and for the duration of the session reference that session field to compute the users notifications.